# DejaVu Sans Mono and upquote

Tags: listings, code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage{upquote}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\begin{document}
\lstinline|4 `div` 2|
\end{document}
```

shows `4 div 2` without the backticks. No errors or warnings in the log. Adding `textcomp` and using `upquote` in `lstset` instead of the separate package didn't help.

Can anyone reproduce it (since search doesn't find anything and it would be weird if I was the first who needed this character)?

And is there a workaround?

Comment: Some months before I discovered that not many fonts contains the backticks even using XeLaTeX... I will test it with XeLaTeX to see if is a matter of font... (I think it is)

Comment: Tested and works fine with XeLaTeX and DejaVu Sans Mono... So, please wait for someone else's answer

Comment: The TS1 fonttable of dejavu Sans is missing quite a lot of glyphs, beside other `\textasciigrave` used by upquote. There is a grave in the font so one could add it, but this means that someone would have to recreate the tfm/enc etc. You could try ``literate={`}{\`{}}2`` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the log file, you'll see

```
Missing character: There is no ` in font DejaVuSansMono-tlf-ts1!
```

The `upquote` package defines `` ` `` to produce `\textasciigrave`, which is taken from the TS1 encoded font. Unfortunately, this glyph is missing in DejaVu Mono in the TS1 encoding. We can borrow it from Vera Sans that has it (thanks to the OP for suggesting it over `cmtt`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\chardef\straightquote@code=\catcode`'
\chardef\backquote@code=\catcode``
\catcode`'=\active \catcode``=\active
\patchcmd{\@noligs}
 {\textasciigrave}
 {\fixedtextasciigrave}
 {}{}
\newcommand{\fixedtextasciigrave}{%
  \makebox[.5em]{\fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont\textasciigrave}% Vera Sans
}
\catcode\lq\'=\straightquote@code
\catcode\lq\`=\backquote@code
\makeatletter

\lstset{
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  literate={`}{{{\fixedtextasciigrave}}}1,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinline|4 `div` 2|

\begin{lstlisting}
4 `div` 2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Since DejaVu is based on Bitstream Vera, I modified the `newcommand` to just `{\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont\textasciigrave}%`. http://www.1001fonts.com/search.html?search=sans+mono&text=%60 shows that DejaVu one should be slightly wider, but it's still much closer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Good idea! I'll incorporate it (with a small change).

Comment: There is an extra closing brace in the command (can't make an edit because it's too small).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov FIxed